# how to sort the key value of a map entry in descending order?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am relatively new to Java, and the whole sort by using comparators is a bit confusing to me.

Is it possible to sort the current output of the code below in descending order without using comparators?

Or is there an easier way for me to understand how to sort said values.

```java
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot , String s) {
        Map<String, Object> userInfo = (Map<String, Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
        String username = (String) userInfo.get("username");

        Map<String, Long> steps = (Map<String, Long>) userInfo.get("steps");

        long existingSteps = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> step : steps.entrySet()) {
            existingSteps += Long.valueOf(step.getValue());
        }

        arrayList.add(new String( username + "  -  " + "steps:  " + existingSteps));

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Leaderboard.this , 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

The current output of this code is:

```
John Doe I - Steps: 79
John Doe II - Steps: 111
John Doe III - Steps: 0
John Doe IV - Steps: 88
John Doe V - Steps: 12
John Doe VI - Steps: 0
```

Is it possible to get this code to run the following output:

```
John Doe II - Steps: 111
John Doe IV - Steps: 88
John Doe I - Steps: 79
John Doe V - Steps: 12
John Doe III - Steps: 0
John Doe VI - Steps: 0
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98NAJ.png)

Comment: use sortmap for java,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values)

Comment: How is `myRef` defined? Please also add your database structure and responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Either use a TreeMap with a custom comparator https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator- or use a SortedSet to get the map values.
But this is all about comparators...

Comment: `DatabaseReference myRef;`
`myRef = database.getReference("user");`                                                                            myRef is defined as stated above @AlexMamo

Comment: Please also add a screenshot to see the content of an object within user node.

Comment: changed the screenshot to one with an open node @AlexMamo

Comment: Since I'm relatively new to it, I don't exactly understand how to use the answers given in your link @DineshShingadiya                                                                                       I've tried to do what they say but I doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Molinho I see now. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of, is to add under each user object, the total number of steps, as a new property. In this case, there is one more thing that you need to do, which is to increment that property with the number of steps that you get every day. Your new schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- user
       |
       --- userId
            |
            --- steps
            |    |
            |    --- //daily steps
            |
            --- target: 100
            |
            --- username: "John Doe I"
            |
            --- totalNumberOfSteps: 111
```

To get the users in (ascending) order according to the `totalNumberOfSteps` property, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("user");
Query query = userRef.orderByChild("totalNumberOfSteps");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String username = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            long totalNumberOfSteps = ds.child("totalNumberOfSteps").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d(TAG, username + " - Steps: " + totalNumberOfSteps);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Then to order it descending, please see my answer from the following post:

- [How to arrange firebase database data in ascending or descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721971/how-to-arrange-firebase-database-data-in-ascending-or-descending-order)

Finally, the result in the logcat will be:

```
John Doe II - Steps: 111
John Doe IV - Steps: 88
John Doe I - Steps: 79
John Doe V - Steps: 12
John Doe III - Steps: 0
John Doe VI - Steps: 0
```

Comment: Does this also include data which gets added later on, for example the steps I walk tomorrow are those taken into account aswell ?

Comment: Yes, it will as long as you update the `totalNumberOfSteps` property daily this the corresponding number of steps.

Comment: Is it possible to make it update automatically, or is manually the only option ?

Comment: You can also make it automatically but you need to write code yourself. The operation is simple, in every user object, iterate throught the `steps` object to get all steps. Once you have the number of all steps, simply write it in the new property. That's it, simple as that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have at the moment, it iterates through the steps with        `long existingSteps = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> step : steps.entrySet()) {
            existingSteps += Long.valueOf(step.getValue());
        }`                                                                                                                             This way it automatically stores the sum in "existingSteps" but then I'm still left with the unsorted pile of numbers. I'll try your method nevertheless, manually isn't a problem either. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yes, in this case you only need to write that value to the database.

Comment: I tried using your code Alex but it doesn't work, it doesn't give any errors, but the order stays the same even when adding the code to order it by ascending order.

Comment: "It doesn't work" will not help me understand the problem and without seeing the code that you are using, I cannot be much of a help.

Comment: I see now, that you have asked another question, which is ussualy the best practice. So I definitely recommend you use Frank van Puffelen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56343559/5246885).

Comment: I've added a property `totalNumberOfSteps` in my database and afterwards added your line of code within my `myRef` statement

Comment: I this case, I recommend you post another fresh question using the entire code you have used, so me and other Firebase developers can help you. The code above works as I tested it before so should also work in your case.

Comment: hopefully you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345948/how-to-get-firebase-data-listed-in-ascending-order-when-using-an-arraylist

Comment: @Molinho Ok, I'll take a look.