# Firebase RealTime Database querying with multiple selected field values in Android not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to query the data from **RealTime Database** based on selected values, but multiple inputs as Arraylist are not working in a single query.

```
 private void readUsers()
    {
     
     DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
     reference.getRoot().equals(query);
        
   Query query12 = reference.child("Users").equals("g@gmail.com");//**how to add multiple email id or as array list**
    query12.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) 
    {
                      
                        for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                           

                        }
    
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
                }
            });
    
        }
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add multiple conditions to the following query:

```
Query query12 = reference.child("Users").equals("g@gmail.com");
```

The `orderBy()` and `equalTo()` methods can be used in a query only once. You can use a range, or why not, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [Firebase multiple queries in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107058/firebase-multiple-queries-in-android)

Comment: in firestore we are able to achieve- Query query = db.collection("users").whereIn("email", Arrays.asList("xyz@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com"));  atleast we are able to send as arraylist  or not?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That operation is perfectly available in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).