# How to use pagination with combined OR queries in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/KdgKvLll07s) on how to achieve pagination with Firestore, however I need to use it with combined queries so I customized my code to look like this:

```
   //combining queries 
    ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String user : following) {
        Task t = postRef.whereEqualTo("publisher", user).orderBy("Date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1).get();
        tasks.add(t);
    }
    //getting the result from combined queries - works fine 
    Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> allTasks = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks);
    allTasks.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
            for (QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : querySnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    PostModel post = document.toObject(PostModel.class);
                    PostsDataHolder.add(post);
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                if (queryDocumentSnapshots.size()>0)lastVisible = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);
            }
            buildRecyclerView();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity()  , PostsDataHolder.size()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        isScrolling = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    int firstVisibileItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                    if (isScrolling && (firstVisibileItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemPaged) {
                        isScrolling = false;
                    //    getting the next queries
                        ArrayList<Task> nextTasks = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (String user : following) {
                            Task t = postRef.whereEqualTo("publisher", user).orderBy("Date").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(1).get();
                            nextTasks.add(t);
                        }

                        //getting the next results - doesn't work i just get the same results as the first query 

                        Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> nextAllTasks = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks);
                        nextAllTasks.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
                                for (QuerySnapshot nextQueryDocumentSnapshots : querySnapshots)
                                {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : nextQueryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                        PostModel post = document.toObject(PostModel.class);
                                        PostsDataHolder.add(post);
                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    if (nextQueryDocumentSnapshots.size() < 1) isLastItemPaged = true;
                                    if (nextQueryDocumentSnapshots.size() > 0)
                                        lastVisible = nextQueryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(nextQueryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);
        }
    });
```

But the posts are just duplicating instead of getting new ones, I have read somewhere in the documentation about `continueWith()` but I don't seem to understand how it works, is that what I'm missing in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "combined queries"?

Comment: Performing a logical OR between them

Comment: There's [no way you can perform a logical OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61107058/firebase-multiple-queries-in-android).

Comment: But it does give me results, I have followed this tutorial over here: https://youtu.be/lneYmqe0qRI
the problem is just that `startAfter()` does not work in my code to achieve pagination

Comment: @AlexMamo OP is performing multiple queries, one per condition. So while you are correct that Firestore doesn't support an OR condition, the code shared here works around that by performing multiple queries.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, I see. Thanks, puf for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to exclude documents from a query.  To that point, if you if you are performing multiple queries (for any reason), it's not possible to have them return only unique documents among those queries.

To put it another way: each query will always return all of the matching document, regardless of any other conditions you might like to impose.  You will have to remove any duplicate documents from your result sets in the code that performs the queries.  There is no alternative or workaround for this.

Comment: Problem is, I'm not getting new data, just the first data I got from `allTasks` being duplicated, do you have any idea how can I edit my code to get new data?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than the one you originally posted.  We can't see your database or your queries, so we really don't know what those queries are going to return.

Comment: I will post a new question showing my database structure