# How to fetch only latest specific data from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database snapshot]

Please see the attached image. As you see there 8 are tables. How can I fetch the latest user-entered data? I can fetch **all data from one table** but hows its possible to get **only the latest entered data from the table individually** ?**

Answer (score 2):

> to get only the latest entered data from the table individually?

Simply by [adding a Timestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data) under each object, [ordering the results descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721971/how-to-arrange-firebase-database-data-in-ascending-or-descending-order) and finally passing `1` as a parameter to Query's [limitToFirst(int limit)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#limitToFirst(int)) method.