# How to sort Firebase data according to Time Created?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

> Hello Everyone, I have loaded some data from Firebase Realtime Database in the App using `Query`.

> This is the Simple code :

```
  Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("name").startAt(data).endAt(data + "\uf8ff");

  options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<HomeModel>().setQuery(query, HomeModel.class).build();
```

> My database structure is simple ;

```
M38dJdquf4jE(the random key)
name : "John Doe"
Image : "image link"
```

> Because of `orderByChild("name")`, whenever a new Data is inserted in the Database is not according to the Time the data is inserted. Instead, it inserts the data in the recyclerView in a Random Order.

> How can I fix it, so that the Last data inserted is always at the last in the recyclerView and not inserted in a random manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because of orderByChild("name"), whenever a new Data is inserted in the Database is not according to the Time

When you are using:

```
.orderByChild("name")
```

It means that the results that are coming from the database will be ordered according to the values that exist in the "name" property, and **not** according to a "time".

> Instead, it inserts the data in the RecyclerView in a Random Order.

As said above, that's definitely not a random order. If you need to get the results according to the "time" of the addition, then you have two options.

If, for example, the "M38dJdquf4jE" is a pushed key that is provided by the "push()" method, you can use Query's [orderBykey()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#orderByKey()) method, which:

> Creates a query in which child nodes are ordered by their keys.

You'll get the results ordered because the pushed keys contain a time component.

If those keys are **not** provided by the "push()" method, to have an order according to a time component, then you should add a property of type "timestamp", as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

Once you have that new property in place, you can use:

```
.orderByChild("timestamp")
```

To have the results ordered ascending. If you need however a descending order, then you can use my answer from the following post:

- [How to arrange firebase database data in ascending or descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721971/how-to-arrange-firebase-database-data-in-ascending-or-descending-order)