# Blank Space in Reversed GridRecyclerView Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

So this is my GridLayout I have declared LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true

```
      var recyclerViewUploaded: RecyclerView? = null
        recyclerViewUploaded = my_posts_recycle
        recyclerViewUploaded.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true )
        recyclerViewUploaded.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        postList = ArrayList()
        postAdapter = MypostsAdapter(this, postList as ArrayList<Post>)
        recyclerViewUploaded.adapter = postAdapter
```

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVwAb.jpg)

See the above image, the problem is it leaves a blank space at the top instead of the bottom.

I have tried using Collections.reverse(postList) but it gives unexpected results the post order 123456 becomes 125643 instead of 654321.

Also postList.reverse() dosen't do anything!

Here is my function to retrive images.

```
  private fun retrievePosts() {
   val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
    postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                (postList as ArrayList<Post>).clear()
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
                    if (post!!.getPublisher() == profileId) {
                        (postList as ArrayList<Post>).add(post)
                    }
                    if (postList.isNullOrEmpty()){
                        swipe_refresh_profile.isRefreshing = false
                    }
                    postList!!.reversed()
                    swipe_refresh_profile.isRefreshing = false
                    postAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
    )
}
```

Here is my JSON database structure

```
 "Posts" : {
"-MYkL70voeqXhrkli7vE" : {
  "caption" : "Setup by:- @iamlokesh_04\n\nSector Kwgt\nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sector.kustom.pack\n\nMini-music Kwgt\nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=minimusicplayerforkwgt.kustom.pack\n\nSelf-made icons\nhttps://t.me/Iamlokesh_04\n\nHope you guys like it  ",
  "postid" : "-MYkL70voeqXhrkli7vE",
  "postimage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-customization.appspot.com/o/Posted%20Pictures%2FAkZI2A4EZbMOHCHPqZp4h4hl2zL2%2F1618940031310.jpg?alt=media&token=946e7836-b032-4d95-93ac-1c04d4342161",
  "publisher" : "AkZI2A4EZbMOHCHPqZp4h4hl2zL2"
},
"-MYkLhERZIZ5az-K3VrQ" : {
  "caption" : "Alpplications used: #37\n\n+Launcher - Nova launcher\n\n+Widgets - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flawlesskwgt.kustom.pack \n\n+Icon Pack - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.panotogomo.darktosca\n\n+Wallpaper - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stark.fluid\n\nTemplate by - https://twitter.com/vhthinh_at?s=09 ",
  "postid" : "-MYkLhERZIZ5az-K3VrQ",
  "postimage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-customization.appspot.com/o/Posted%20Pictures%2FAkZI2A4EZbMOHCHPqZp4h4hl2zL2%2F1618940184176.jpg?alt=media&token=f6ced789-be42-4d72-873f-8316ce557ff9",
  "publisher" : "AkZI2A4EZbMOHCHPqZp4h4hl2zL2"
},
"-MYkLpNkeHPEWwmYDgwN" : {
  "caption" : "Rate my Setup!!  ",
  "postid" : "-MYkLpNkeHPEWwmYDgwN",
  "postimage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-customization.appspot.com/o/Posted%20Pictures%2FAkZI2A4EZbMOHCHPqZp4h4hl2zL2%2F1618940216883.jpg?alt=media&token=59c0b67e-bd5c-4b6c-9c14-36e16676bf58",
  "publisher" : "AkZI2A4EZbMOHCHPqZp4h4hl2zL2"
}
```

]

Here if the posts have the publisherid same as the profile id get added into the postList List.

I am finding a solution for this for a long time, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo Done, kindly recheck

Comment: Where in your object can I find that ID, for example, "125643"?

Comment: @AlexMamo Sir, I mentioned it as the order of posts 1 2 3 4 5 6 are getting rearranged differently as opposed to 6 5 4 3 2 1, it's not an object.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721971/how-to-arrange-firebase-database-data-in-ascending-or-descending-order).

Comment: The `reverse` should work. Given the JSON you shared, can you show the order in which you expect the posts to show up in the view?