# Sort data to RecyclerView based on latest date from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android chat application in which I need to order the conversation details by the date. My firebase data structure is mentioned below.

[image: Database structure]

Now I want to retrieve and show the data on the latest date on my RecyclerView from Firebase Realtime Database based on timestamp.

I have tried the following approaches.

```
final DatabaseReference nm =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Transaction");

Query query = nm.orderByChild("Date").limitToFirst(5);
;

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listData.clear();
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Transaction ld = npsnapshot.getValue(Transaction.class);

                listData.add(ld);
            }
            Tadapter = new TransactionAdapter(listData);
            rv.setAdapter(Tadapter);
            Log.d(TAG, "Total Count" + Tadapter.getItemCount());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am developing an android chat application in which I need to order the conversation details by the date.

As I see in your screenshot, your `Date` property is of type String. This means that you cannot call:

```
.orderByChild("Date")
```

And expect to behave as it was a Timestamp. When you order String elements, the order that you get is always [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). This means that Strings doesn't consider any sort of numeric values when sorting, especially when it comes to the dates, even if the dates contain numbers, as your first element does:

```
Date: "30/7/2021"
```

So using String values when querying your database it's not an option. However, I see you already have a `Timestamp` property. Maybe on that property, it was supposed to do the ordering. If that was not the case, I suggest you change the type of the `Date` property from String to Timestamp, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

> Now I want to retrieve and show the data on the latest date on my RecyclerView

This means that most likely you need to reverse the order, meaning that all your transactions have to be displayed in your RecyclerView descending. In this case, there are a few options that you have, either on the server or on the client.

Assuming that you have changed the type of your `Date` property from String to Timestamp, then you can simply consider storing an inverted Timestamp value like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- transactions
        |
        --- 1
            |
            --- Date: 1627714194
            |
            --- invertedDate: -1627714194
```

See, the `invertedDate` property holds a negative value. Since by default, the elements are ordered ascending, to be able to order the transaction desecendiong, you should simply use:

```
Query query = nm.orderByChild("invertedDate").limitToFirst(5);
```

On the other hand, there are some workarounds that can be made to achieve the same thing on the client, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to arrange firebase database data in ascending or descending order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721971/how-to-arrange-firebase-database-data-in-ascending-or-descending-order)

Answer (score 0):

```java
Query query = nm.orderByChild("Date").limitToFirst(5);
```

Firebase realtime database sorts in ascending order that means those 5 nodes that you'll receive will be the oldest.

> I want to retrieve and show the data in latest date

Try using `limitToLast` instead which will return the last 5 documents after ordering the nodes by Date field i.e. the 5 latest nodes.

```java
Query query = nm.orderByChild("Date").limitToLast(5);
```

You can read more about that at [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).