# Firebase desc sorting orderbychild not working after user re-login

Tags: android, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have no issue sorting my database in descending order by using `orderbychild(-timestamp)` in firebaseRecycleradapter.

```
 final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserChat, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserChat, BlogViewHolder>(
            UserChat.class,
            R.layout.userchatrow,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mUserChatList.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("UserList").orderByChild("negatedtime")
           //descending order
    ) {
```

However, when user is logged out using `Auth.getinstance.signOut` and `LoginManager.getinstance.logOut`, then log in again (either facebook, google or email), firebase database can no longer fetching latest result via `orderbychild(-timestamp)`. When I deleted `orderbychild(-timestamp)`, it can retrieve the latest result, but in ascending order which is not I want.

```
final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserChat, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserChat, BlogViewHolder>(
            UserChat.class,
            R.layout.userchatrow,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mUserChatList.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("UserList")
             //ascending order
    ) {
```

I can't reverse the LayoutManager nor RecyclerView, or the other approaches such as reversing the ArrayList order as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android) as the key is not a push ID, the only way to sort to the latest is by `orderbychild(-timestamp)`.

I did not use `setPersistenceEnable` and `keepSynced`, so as not to cache any memory on user phone, but to no avail.

Any helps?

Comment: Please add the code you using.

Comment: Are you using persistanceEnabled ??
Check

Comment: I did not use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true or false);`. Is it being set to true by default?

Comment: It defaults to `false`. Leave it as is, it shouldn't affect your query results.

Comment: You say "firebase database can no longer fetching latest result via `orderbychild(-timestamp)`". What goes wrong when you use `mUserChatList.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("UserList").orderByChild("negatedtime")` after the user logged out and back in again? It seems extremely unlikely that the same code returns the children in a different order then.

Comment: When user logged out and back in again, if there is a latest node added in there, it can't retrieve the latest result and sort it descending from there, it still sorts it from the last negatedtime (last previous node).

Comment: However, I managed to solve them ridiculously, and I not sure how and why.. The way I solved it was placing a `mUserChatList.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("UserList").addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` without `orderByChild("negatedtime")`  before the firebaserecyclerAdapter, and other code remains the same.