# How can i read data from firebase using LIFO rules

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i can read data normally but when i want to read data from firebase using rules of LIFO this time i can't read any kind of data . but i want to read data from firebase which data come my firebase last time

```
 dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String root_order = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    for (long i = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); i <= 0; i--) {
                        studentList.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Student student = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                            studentList.add(student);
                        }
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            });


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5pPw.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit ordering of data in Firebase, so "last in" only has meaning if your data structure ensures so.

For example, if you use Firebase's `push()` method to add new children, then they have keys that are constantly lexicographically increasing. In that case you can get only the most recent item with:

```
dref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

---

If you're not using `push()`, then the only way to get the most recent item is if  you ensure there is a property with the timestamp in each child node, typically by [writing a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps). Once you have such a timestamp in each child, you can get the most recent item with:

```
dref.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

Comment: Sir , i use limitToLast(1) method then i get just last item, if i use limiToLast(2) then i get just last 2 item but i want to read all of data last to first like if i have 3 data are a,b,c,d ; i want to read d,c,b,a

Comment: Ah, you want to get the items descending? That is not possible in the Firebase Realtime Database, all queries are ascending. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("node name")
           .orderByKey().endAt(lastKey).limitToLast(5);
```

You can use `ChildEventListener` if you need data one by one.

```
query.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

You can use `ValueEventListener` if you need a complete snapshot of the node.

```
query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```