# How to sort data from Firebase Realtime Database by value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the data below from a Firebase Realtime Database and want to sort data entries by their value.

How can I convert the following data

```
{
  "scores": {
    "bruhathkayosaurus" : 55,
    "lambeosaurus" : 21,
    "linhenykus" : 80,
    "pterodactyl" : 93,
    "stegosaurus" : 5,
    "triceratops" : 22
  }
}
```

to this

```
{
  "scores": {
    "pterodactyl" : 93,
    "linhenykus" : 80,
    "bruhathkayosaurus" : 55,
    "triceratops" : 22
    "lambeosaurus" : 21,
    "stegosaurus" : 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Data Desc Sorting in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where is your code to get this data? where is your database structure? you need to post this as well, otherwise, how can we find your problem dear?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Please also responde with @AlexMamo