# Query not returning correct items in list. Should return items with largest count and list limit should be 15 items

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to make it so that the ArrayList can only have 15 items. I have tried the two obvious things that one could do which is:

`if (mPostList.size() < 15)`

and

`if (mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() < 15)`

I have tried both of those approaches, but they don't return the correct items. The items that are to be queried are by `count` from the most to the least, and both of those return random items that shouldn't be in the list.

Below you have the whole method for context. What can I do so that I get back the posts with the biggest `count` and only have 15 items in the list?

If I change it to `DatabaseReference` instead of `Query` it works but takes WAY TOO LONG.

Need it to be ordered by `count` and set the list limit to 15 items.

So how can I limit the list to 15 items for `Query`?

```
Posts
    -MFv4Q2HuSMeO20jFdvn
        city: "New Orleans"
        count: 13
        description: "Who's down for a little nature hike with some g..."
        postid: "-MFv4Q2HuSMeO20jFdvn"
        postimage: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eve..."
        publisher: "p3IeqP273ogiWuexi6w0bNGm9Mo2"
        location: "2615 Stonebriar Ridge Ct"
        timestamp: 1598719111494
```

```
        private void readPosts() {
            Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("count");
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    mPostList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                            mPostList.add(post);
                    }
    
                    if (mPostList.size() == 0) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mNoEventsFoundTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mNoEventsFoundTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
    
                    Collections.sort(mPostList, (Post o1, Post o2) -> Long.compare(o2.getCount(), o1.getCount()));
                    mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. What is the result that you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo I just get the first 15 back order by date because I am assuming it's reading all the posts' ```count``` and adds them to the list and because there can only be 15 it adds the first 15 instead of looping through all and returning the 15 that have the largest ```count```.

Comment: @Andy doesn't work. Yes... Just gives me back first 15 posts in the database.

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it for that purpose) to include: 1) the JSON at `Posts` (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) what nodes from that JSON you'd expect to see in your adapter in what order.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so that's what the data of each post looks like and I need to order them by ```count``` (max to min) and only 15 items can be in the list. As mentioned with ```DatabaseReference``` as variable type it works and I can do it, but takes much too long to load posts. I want it to just read the ```count``` of each post which is why I did ```Query```, ```orderByChild()``` and return them in order of max to min with only 15 items in the list.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any suggestions? If not I'll just do DatabaseReference and that's that... Seems odd there isn't something like this for Query though.

Comment: "I need to order them by `count` (max to min)" Firebase Realtime Database always returns query results in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries always return the matching nodes in ascending order. So if you want the 15 items with the highest values, you have two options:

1. Get the **last** 15 items from the list, and then reverse those client-side. The query for this would look like this:

   ```
   query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                           .orderByChild("count").limitToLast(15)
   ```
2. Store an inverted `count` value in each child node too, and order on that. So each JSON would then look like this:

   ```
   Posts
       -MFv4Q2HuSMeO20jFdvn
           city: "New Orleans"
           count: 13
           invertedCount: -13
           ...
   ```

   And the query would be:

   ```
   query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
                           .orderByChild("invertedCount").limitToFirst(15)
   ```

Also see:

- [Firebase Data Desc Sorting in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android)

Comment: Well, that did it. Didn't know that. Anyways, thanks man. I appreciate it. I was using ```limitToFirst(15)``` originally which wasn't doing it, so now I'll know. Thanks!