# How to get children in descending order in Android Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my RealTime Database pic.

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXHmc.png)

how can i get key in descending order. like example:[1617777000000, 1617301800000, 1617258600000] instead ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database returns list in ascending order, you have to reverse the list client side, or find some other way.

But this question was asnwers here [Descending Order Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android)